# what is the meaning of " was to be reached" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

It was by this time well known to the Romans that there were two, and two only, convenient roads whereby Southern Mesopotamia was to be reached, one along ...

Comment: Old-fashioned for 'could be reached'. I'd go with ' ... two, and only two, ...'.

Answer (score 1):

The prepositional phrase "whereby Southern Mesopotamia was to be reached" means that Southern Mesopotamia could be (only) reached by the aforementioned two "convenient roads."